# How to solve webpack error loader.js: 979

Tags: node.js, webpack

I m totaly new to webpack.

```
const path = require('path');
console.log(__dirname)
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/app.js',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  }
};
```

This is my 1st web pack configaration. but in terminal when i m trying provide this command  `"node webpack.config.js"` then it gives me `internal/module/cjs/loader.js:979 error`.

[image]

My Goal is just to print the absolute path which i defined in `console.log(__dirname)`. Please Help Me

Comment: You don't execute the webpack config via node. It's a file that the webpack module looks for to know how to handle your files. Check the docs.

Comment: oke i got you. but i really don't caught up  when i run command node webpack.config.js . it gives me a error. is it web pack error or something. and it is also saying that it cannot find module H:\Study\react\Indecision-app\webpack.config.js.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
var loc = window.location.pathname;
var dir = loc.substring(0, loc.lastIndexOf('/'));
```

Regards